# Does the 140W USB-C Power Adapter work on MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I read this other question for a problem that i have([MacBook Pro not charging under heavy load](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370156/macbook-pro-not-charging-under-heavy-load))

Since I do React native development, it seems to be chugging hard on my battery, and since it appears to be normal see the answer attached, I started looking for other chargers that might be capable to provide more Watt... And I stumbled on the 140W USB-C power adapter from apple.

[Here's the listing](https://apple.com/shop/product/MLYU3AM/A/140w-usb-c-power-adapter?fnode=ff804511c7c4abaf28f40428203e2da89da50a4f6720574a021f18a14ef6e0404064c9ef251c658c5206cb53073cbfb813d4bd81f3b7ac82350fefcef8bd4ae1f682845c444b68219b97f0465bffb12b82938e10731e8feca50afc5ac77e542e)

Under compatibility, the MacBook is listed but in the description, it suggests the 2021 model... so I was wondering if the charger will give my MacBook pro the 140W or just the 96W as the other charger..?

Comment: Surely it'll help; when under heavy CPU/GPU load even the battery becomes a power supply (and start discharging faster than when idling) — due to AC adapter's inability to provide enough power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just 96W as the other charger.

It is not the charger that decides how much power a computer is charged with. The computers draws the power from the charger - and the MacBook Pro 16-inch (2019) will only draw 96 watts. That goes even when the charger is capable of delivering more power.

You might instead want to look into conserving power. For example it could be that you have programs unnecessarily running and consuming CPU, or it could be that an update exists for some of your software that is more energy efficient.

You can also try for example lowering the brightness on the internal display to save power.

Answer (score 0):

The power rating of the adaptor is the *maximum* it can supply. It's not a hose that always pushes that much juice through the pipe.

The device takes what it can use. If Apple made a 500W adaptor, your Mac wouldn't get 500W.