Can I use 45W charger with 2015 MacBook Pro 13"?
Original charger was 60W but it is no longer working.
If I use a 45W charger, would it cause any kind of problems in the long term?

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/370156/237687

There's no harm in using an under-rated power source.
The only issue is whether the rate of energy going in is more than the rate at which the laptop is consuming the energy.
If you try to use the laptop while the battery is charging, then it may charge only very slowly. Or not at all. Or, the battery may still go down, but slower than without the charger.

Without a charger, your battery will go from 100% to 0% through the day. With a 45 Watt charger, if you use lots of power all the time, it might go from 100% to 60%. Less low if you don't use power all the time, lower if you use a lot of power, but you are always better off than without a charger. And overnight, 45 Watt is enough to recharge the battery.
